# How to avoid cursor issue?

Tags: asp.net

I have created one form.When I running the form,every where it is(including text also) showing hand instead of arrow(other than textbox).What shall I do to avoid this?

Comment: do you use some css ? if so, look for the "cursor" attribute

Comment: Is the page still busy loading some resource?

Answer (score 1):

put this in header part

```
 <style type="text/css">
        body {
            cursor: default;
        }
    </style>
```

hope it helps ...